# How can I drag the VLOOKUP function down for multiple outputs instead of just one?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell, vlookup

I'm trying to lookup a value within a table, and that table has multiple lookup values associated to the output.

For example, I want to lookup Banana, and in my table, Banana is associated with multiple users with a different name. I want to output all of those different names associated with Banana.

`=VLOOKUP("Banana",A$1:D$10,2,FALSE)`

Stacey, Michael and Joe are associated with Banana respectively. When I input the formula in the first cell, it outputs Stacey, and when I drag the formula down, it only outputs Stacey, and not the other names.

My caculation is set to auto aswell.

How can I output each name associated with Banana without only copying down one name?

Comment: This post might be a good starting point for you: http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

> This is an array formula, if you were to see the sample image below you will notice at the beginning and ending of the formula there is "**{**" "**}**". So after you copy & paste the formula below on a cell, (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) and you will see the {} added on the formula bar.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8; SMALL(IF(EXACT($E$1;$B$2:$B$8); 
 ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1); ROW(1:1)));"")
```

Hope this may help you.

Please refer: 
**Sample Output**

[image]